Method getDataAt is not supported for Array(String): while pushing to view otel.test_xxx (xxx). (NOT_IMPLEMENTED) (version 23.3.16.7 (official build))
I deploy a clickchouse docker with version 23.3.16.7 (official build) , after config clickhouse graphite rollup and create a MATERIALIZED VIEW and one GraphiteMergeTree ，I had a error when insert data like below:
Code: 48. DB::Exception: Method getDataAt is not supported for Array(String): while pushing to view otel.test_830e1527_c8f9_4801_8e0f_dfe4384acce0_17 (e2b196c0-70e7-457e-95f2-75926952c939). (NOT_IMPLEMENTED) (version 23.3.16.7 (official build))

NOTE:  clickchouse version  22.1.3.7  is totally  fine
Details:
I hava a MergeTree to save log data:
-- otel.test definition

CREATE TABLE otel.test
(

    `Timestamp` DateTime64(9) CODEC(Delta(8),
 ZSTD(1)),

    `TraceId` String CODEC(ZSTD(1)),

    `SpanId` String CODEC(ZSTD(1)),

    `TraceFlags` UInt32 CODEC(ZSTD(1)),

    `SeverityText` LowCardinality(String) CODEC(ZSTD(1)),

    `SeverityNumber` Int32 CODEC(ZSTD(1)),

    `ServiceName` LowCardinality(String) CODEC(ZSTD(1)),

    `Body` String CODEC(ZSTD(1))
)
ENGINE = MergeTree
PARTITION BY toDate(Timestamp)
ORDER BY toUnixTimestamp(Timestamp)
TTL toDateTime(Timestamp) + toIntervalDay(14)
SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192,
 ttl_only_drop_parts = 1;

then ，I need to aggregate some thing， so i use clickhouse graphite feature:
first , create config.d/graphite_rollup.xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<yandex>
  <graphite_rollup>
    <path_column_name>tags</path_column_name>
    <time_column_name>ts</time_column_name>
    <value_column_name>val</value_column_name>
    <version_column_name>updated</version_column_name>
    <default>
      <function>sum</function>
      <retention>
        <age>0</age>
        <precision>1</precision>
      </retention>
      <retention>
        <age>360</age>
        <precision>60</precision>
      </retention>
      <retention>
        <age>3600</age>
        <precision>300</precision>
      </retention>
      <retention>
        <age>86400</age>
        <precision>3600</precision>
      </retention>
    </default>
  </graphite_rollup>
</yandex>

and restart docker like this:
docker run -d --name clickhouse-server \
-p 8123:8123 \
-p 9009:9009 \
-p 9090:9000 \
--ulimit nofile=262144:262144 \
--volume=/Users/jasber/tmp/clickhouse/data:/var/lib/clickhouse \
--volume=/Users/jasber/tmp/clickhouse/log:/var/log/clickhouse-server \
--volume=/Users/jasber/tmp/clickhouse/conf/config.xml:/etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml \
--volume=/Users/jasber/tmp/clickhouse/conf/users.xml:/etc/clickhouse-server/users.xml \
--volume=/Users/jasber/tmp/clickhouse/config.d/:/etc/clickhouse-server/config.d/ \
--restart=always \
yandex/clickhouse-server

then i create a GraphiteMergeTree using graphite_rollup.
-- metrics.samples definition

CREATE TABLE metrics.samples
(

    `date` Date DEFAULT toDate(0),

    `name` String,

    `tags` Array(String),

    `val` Float64,

    `ts` DateTime,

    `updated` DateTime DEFAULT now()
)
ENGINE = GraphiteMergeTree('graphite_rollup')
PARTITION BY date
ORDER BY (name,
 tags,
 ts)
SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192;

and create a MATERIALIZED VIEW from otel.test to metrics.samples
-- otel.test_830e1527_c8f9_4801_8e0f_dfe4384acce0_17 source

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW otel.test_830e1527_c8f9_4801_8e0f_dfe4384acce0_17 TO metrics.samples
(

    `date` Date,

    `name` String,

    `tags` Array(String),

    `val` Float64,

    `ts` DateTime64(9),

    `updated` DateTime
) AS
SELECT
    toDate(Timestamp) AS date,

    'clickvisual_alert_metrics' AS name,

    ['uuid=830e1527-c8f9-4801-8e0f-dfe4384acce0',
 'alarmId=14',
 'filterId=17'] AS tags,

    toFloat64(count(*)) AS val,

    Timestamp AS ts,

    toDateTime(Timestamp) AS updated
FROM otel.test
WHERE 1 = 1
GROUP BY Timestamp;

after all. i test it , when i insert data to otel.test
INSERT
    INTO
    otel.test
(`Timestamp`,
    TraceId,
    SpanId,
    TraceFlags,
    SeverityText,
    SeverityNumber,
    ServiceName,
    Body)
VALUES(now64(),
'11111111111',
'',
0,
'',
0,
'',
'2024-11-04T18:19:15.466502878+08:00ERROR ipam/agent.go:212'
);

the error comes (data is absolute inserted ， but error comes when MATERIALIZED VIEW aggregate data and save to GraphiteMergeTree)
so ， how to fix it？ click 22.1.3.7 is ok ,but  click 23.3.16.7 is wrong
I try to change graphite rollup
from
<path_column_name>tags</path_column_name>

to
<path_column_name>name</path_column_name>

the error will not come again.
but ，someone told me ，do not do This， it will produce some uncertain effects
when Prometheus to read time data through prom2click .

Code: 48. DB::Exception: Method getDataAt is not supported for Array(String): while pushing to view otel.test_830e1527_c8f9_4801_8e0f_dfe4384acce0_17 (e2b196c0-70e7-457e-95f2-75926952c939). (NOT_IMPLEMENTED) (version 23.3.16.7 (official build))
Code: 48. DB::Exception: Method getDataAt is not supported for Array(String): while pushing to view otel.test_830e1527_c8f9_4801_8e0f_dfe4384acce0_17 (e2b196c0-70e7-457e-95f2-75926952c939). (NOT_IMPLEMENTED) (version 23.3.16.7 (official build))
